# Redux-saga and Forward/Backward opportunity

Tags: reactjs, workflow, redux, redux-saga

I've developing kiosk application (user interface), and need to describe different scenarios of payment.

To describe UI-elements, was choosen a React. I liked the Redux for the one direction of data flow. But in this architecture I didn't knew where put the business logic to describe different workflows. In research, I found the wonderful module - redux-saga. I understood, that this module can be like process manager, and I found that many people thought like this.

But with redux-saga not all so clear, as I wanted, so I write my questions here.

Main thought that i have one big workflow, separated with steps. For example, process - payment cellular by phone number. It's look like this:

Process payment cellular:

- Enter phone number
- Online check number

  - Bad response: Error

    - Backward: Enter phone number
- Confirm information
- Put the cash
- Make payment

  - Bad response: Error

    - Backward: Exit from process payment cellular
- Information about transaction

In my vision every stage is a saga, that will call from previous stage. It's all cool, until I need to give to the user an opportunity go to the previous stage, for example, from Confirmation backward to Enter phone number.

So question, how to manage stages in my main workflow, if I can forward from one stage to another, and go back?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check "Wizard" example in [redux-saga-examples](https://github.com/kuy/redux-saga-examples).

Demo: http://kuy.github.io/redux-saga-examples/wizard.html
Code: https://github.com/kuy/redux-saga-examples/tree/master/wizard

This example has 3 wizard pages "start", "verify", and "pay".
"verify" step is a verification step that confirms an email address given in "start" step. If verification succeeds, the wizard forwards to "pay" step. If not, you will back to "start" step.

In addition to these normal flows, you can manually go back to "start" step from "verify" step while verification (it takes 5 seconds). The ongoing verification process will be cancelled when you back to "start" step.

Comment: Thank you!

One more useful example:

https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/576#issuecomment-252557319